# PHP CMS with powerful in-place editing?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a good, clean PHP-based CMS that has as powerful in-place editing functions as [Apostrophe](http://www.apostrophenow.com/) which is great, but out of the question because of its strong reliance on Symphony and command-line tools that I can't use for this project. (As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547379/apostrophe-cms-hosting-questions-feasible-to-get-into-without-symfony-experien), with a nice contribution from one of Apostrophe's developers! You don't get that every day.)

"In-place" means that almost all editing work (adding content, deleting content, managing media...) takes place in the front-end of the web site, with a small menu in the screen's corner leading to everything else.

Consequently executed, this is an extremely intuitive approach that is very easy to use for end-users a whole lot because of the "point-click-and-type" philosophy.

Does anybody have any solid recommendations?

Comment: did you try anything out yet?

Comment: @chelmertz not yet, but I will in the next couple of weeks. Will leave feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took alot of searching to find this but it sounds like [Exponent CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_CMS) is your best bet for getting as close to Apostrophe as you can.  I provided the wiki link so you could view the demo link at the bottom and the website link for downloading.

No matter what CMS you go with you will need to learn the syntax and methods.  Symfony "can" be done all manually by just creating the files yourself instead of having the symfony file create them for you.  Should you need to run command line commands, you could always run exec() from php.

Comment: Cheers, I will take a good look at this.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with using @John's recommendation, GetSimple, because of its extremely simplistic nature, and XML-basedness. However, it doesn't have in-place editing. Exponent seems to come closest to that, so I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Concrete 5](http://www.concrete5.org/). It used to be proprietary but not anymore and is built using the Zend Framework.

Another CMS that has similar (if not better) functionality but is fairly new is [ImpressPages](http://www.impresspages.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Drupal has no seperate backend, all front end stuff. You can use admin panel to still create a good lookin admin panel in your front end though.

All content basically has the tabs 
- view
- edit
- revisions
- translate

And any other action you can undertake, same with users.

Drupal's pro's are simple build(no MVC or OOP), large open source community, thousands of modules and module writing for Drupal isn't very complicated.

I see you tagged this wysywig, Drupal allows simple switching between editors and allowed input formats when editing content. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 You might want to checkout [Drupal Gardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com) to see the goodies that Drupal 7 (currently in development, release should be somewhere in late 2010, early 2011) will bring... The learning curve can be pretty steep though.

Comment: Yes, drupal's config is pretty expanded but it's not to bad imo. Just I like the api documentation as well, very clear and easy, imo much better then I have seen on other CMS systems. Downside is that because there is no seperate admin panel, if you switch to a self made theme your admin forms can look like crap. there's some default CSS but what you really need.

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Pimcore](http://www.pimcore.org/). It provides inline editing and previewing each page in an easy manner.

- [Demo video of drag & drop interface](http://www.pimcore.org/features/cms/drag-n-drop)
- [Demo video of editing a page](http://vimeo.com/10850668)

It's built on top of Zend Framework and pretty easy to extend.

> "In-place" means that almost all
>   editing work (adding content, deleting
>   content, managing media...) takes
>   place in the front-end of the web site
>   [...]

Well, the admin is at `/admin` but there are "preview" buttons for the view of the page currently being edited, and the WYSIWYG does a very good job with keeping a similar layout of the actual layout of the page (i.e. inserting inputs and other form controls right on the elements).

Answer (score 3):

I looked at quite a lot of CMS's and at the end of the day I found this one.

GetSimple
http://get-simple.info/

Its a really great, tiny CMS that is just a very simple and efficient CMS that is easily modifiable.

There is a such a great saying, "With great power comes great responsibility", for me the worst thing that could happen is if you CMS is hacked, goes down and you cannot figure out what software update caused it, I think you are going to stress a lot. Get Simple is very elegant, small and easy to work with.

Highly recommended but might not be suitable for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be at least 2 wordpress [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/edit-in-place) that enable in place editing.

I don't know what features Apostrophe offers and neither did I try the WP-plugins so I can't compare them.